# Switching AC without Electro-Mechanical Relay

Tags: driver, isolation, triac

I'm working on a design where I need to switch an AC signal but do not want to use electro-mechanical relays to do so. I have bread-boarded the below circuit, cycled > 5000 times to verify it as a potential solution. I have been unable to get much support from triac driver MFG, I'm not sure they understand what I'm trying to achieve, or they do not want to touch it. Hard to discern.

The schematic shows what I'm doing. The triac driver MFG replies only that it needs to go to a triac to drive the load, which I understand. But the AC load through pin 6 and pin 4 is 31.5mA.

PCB 1 and PCB 2 have their own separate 24VAC XFMR, so I need to isolate and would rather not tie in commons (half wave rectifier on main PCB power supplies)

Anyone have input??[image]

Comment: So what is it you are "trying to achieve"? You need to ask explicit questions. Best to enumerate them: A Question 1..., B Question 2..., C, D, etc. "Anyone have input?" is not a good question to ask in a forum like this. Reading your posting I'm not even sure if you have a problem, let alone what it might be. You imply that the circuit has worked "5,000 times". That doesn't sound like a problem!

Comment: Yes, working too fast, my bad.                                             A. Using a triac driver to switch the circuit as shown. Is there any reason to believe this would not work or represents a problem, long term.                                                            B. Is there a better means of accomplishing what I'm looking to, switching low current AC with solid state component(s).

Comment: I don't get it. What is the purpose of the circuit? Why is there AC involved? It looks like all you are doing is communicating between two voltage-isolated micro's: you set a bit on the micro on the left, and output a bit to a micro on the right? Is that all you are trying to do? See? You are not explaining your device or your problem.

Comment: You nailed it on the logic side. A/C is involved because it is an existing circuit that I must retro-fit / make backwards compatible. I am trying to improve on existing design which uses electro-mechanical relays to switch the A/C. Not sure what bearing any of that has to do with my question. But, there it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, that will work. It operates the triac at much lower currents than is normally envisioned, but I expect no problems.

That said, I'd be inclined to make the following changes.

1) Move the switching element to pcb B, and just run the control wires between the boards.

2) Don't try to interrupt the AC. Keep the 47 uF charged all the time. Use a standard optocoupler (specifically not a triac, since a triac will not interrupt DC to turn off the signal) to drive the transistor. If you're worried about wasting power in the zener, couple the cap to the 680 resistor. Otherwise, run the zener continuously and couple 5 V to the 1300 ohm resistor.

3) Cut the power rating of the 25 ohm resistor. No way will it dissipate 3 watts - an average of 1/4 watt is more like it, so a 1/2 watt unit should do, maybe a 1 watt if you're feeling paranoid.

The point is that you're not actually trying to switch AC. You're trying to produce a DC level when AC is present, and that's an entirely different problem.

Comment: To clarify change 2): "standard optocoupler" = an optocoupler with a phototransistor or photodiode output, **not** an optotriac output like OP currently has. An optotriac would never reset with DC flowing trough it.

Comment: @jms - Right you are, and I guess I shouldn't have assumed that was obvious. I've edited. Thanks.